# Can't launch applications, no windows, no launcher, nothing but a blank desktop

Tags: hud, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I unchecked unity tool bar from Compiz, after that no windows and launcher are visible. Also no applications are launching. I rebooted the system but no use. I can now see only a blank desktop nothing else. I am not able to launch even the terminal.

The only thing that I can do is just right-click on the desktop and change the desktop background.